# Java8/JBoss7 - Can't get instance of bean

Tags: java, java-8, jboss, wildfly, jndi

I'm upgrading an app from JBoss 5 to 7 and I've been running into an issue where it can't find the bean which has been called.

Which of the JNDI bindings JBoss is actually looking for?

**server.log** (on startup)

```
WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ManagerLocal' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "Application-EJB.jar" of deployment "Application-EAR.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/Application-EAR/Application-EJB/ManagerLocal!com.application.data.manager.local.ManagerLocal
    java:app/Application-EJB/ManagerLocal!com.application.data.manager.local.ManagerLocal
    java:module/ManagerLocal!com.application.data.manager.local.ManagerLocal
    java:global/Application-EAR/Application-EJB/ManagerLocal
    java:app/Application-EJB/ManagerLocal
    java:module/ManagerLocal
```

**Error**

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ManagerLocal -- service jboss.naming.context.java.ManagerLocal
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.common.util.LookupUtil.lookup(LookupUtil.java:91)
    at com.common.util.LookupUtil.lookupLocalBean(LookupUtil.java:35)
    at com.application.web.resource.RequestResource.getRequestManager(RequestResource.java:69)
    at com.application.web.resource.RequestResource.searchRequests(RequestResource.java:413)
    at com.application.trigger.handler.TriggerHandler.execute(TriggerHandler.java:43)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
2018-10-05 16:25:00,030 [ApplicationScheduler_Worker-3] ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job AppJobs.AppBuild threw an unhandled Exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't get an instance of manager bean
```

**Code to compute JNDI name**

```
private static String computeJNDIName(boolean isLocal, String beanName, String appName) {
        String name;

        if (isLocal) {
            name = appName + "/" + beanName + "/local";
        } else {
            name = appName + "/" + beanName + "/remote";
        }

        return name;
    }
```

Comment: Following up PT_C - did this get you going?

Comment: @JGlass yes/no. I edited the `computeJNDIName` method to tack on `java:global/Application-EAR/Application-EJB/ManagerLocal + name` and it seems to have gotten passed it and on to the next error. Not sure if it's best practice however.

Comment: Glad you got it going PT_C!  I was going to delete my answer - but just in case someone is having a similar issue and stumbles upon your question and my answer helps them I'll leave it.  Did you get the Vault code working from your other question?

Comment: @JGlass yes that one worked like a charm!! Appreciate the help

Comment: Awesome man - when you get time, and if you can tweak the code a bit to not anger the RH overlords - you might answer your own question.  Else if you don't feel like it I can just answer it with some verbiage from the RH page, the link again - and maybe you'll accept it ;-)  but you have less reputation than I do so IMHO you might do it to build more!

Answer (score 0):

Not the greatest answer, e.g. it doesnt state the why or reasoning, but I had to add this to a JSF backing bean in my WAR so it could access a bean in the EJB jar when I upgraded to EAP7

```
@EJB(lookup="java:app/NEDtoBrsMigratorEJB/CustomerDeleterBean")
CustomerDeleterBeanLocal customerDeleterBean;
```

The JNDI binding for the EJB is:

> java:global/NEDtoBrsMigratorEAR/NEDtoBrsMigratorEJB/CustomerDeleterBean!net.myco.brsupdater.engine.CustomerDeleterBeanLocal
>   java:app/NEDtoBrsMigratorEJB/CustomerDeleterBean!net.myco.brsupdater.engine.CustomerDeleterBeanLocal
>   java:module/CustomerDeleterBean!net.myco.brsupdater.engine.CustomerDeleterBeanLocal
>   java:global/NEDtoBrsMigratorEAR/NEDtoBrsMigratorEJB/CustomerDeleterBean
>   java:app/NEDtoBrsMigratorEJB/CustomerDeleterBean
>   java:module/CustomerDeleterBean

And note, that example annotation is for in VM JNDI lookup.

Comment: This help get you going at all @PT_C ?

Comment: I was going to delete this as @PT_C got it working in another manner but I'll leave it just in case it possibly helps someone else out that has similar issues migrating from JBoss 5 to 7.